# 405 Method Not Allowed

Tags: services, entities

I am using [services](https://www.drupal.org/project/services) module with [Universally Unique IDentifier](https://www.drupal.org/project/uuid) to exposed some services.

Everything was working fine. But from 3-4 days back i am facing a issue.

Whenever i am using PUT method to update my comment or node.I am getting following error :

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>405 Method Not Allowed</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Method Not Allowed</h1>
        <p>The requested method PUT is not allowed for the URL /index.php.</p>
        <hr>
        <address>Apache/2.2.16 (Debian) Server at example.com Port 8091</address>
    </body>
</html>
```

I never changed anything in my code since 3-4 month.

May be some one help me to fix this issue

Comment: from above error, URL seems to be the site home page. Can you share the Service URL and parameters passed to it, that will help debug more.

Comment: This isn't something that can be debugged externally, it's your server config. A 405 means that your server has rejected a request with a specific method (HEAD, GET, PUT, OPTIONS, etc). There isn't much point in trying to guess what might have changed from here, that's something you'll need to look at server logs for